# Mailer [SMTP] is not defined. when I am sending email in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-mail

I face a problem it the first I see this problem in Laravel 7.

```
InvalidArgumentException: Mailer [SMTP] is not defined. in file /home1/clinicph/clinic/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php on line 110
```

and this is my .env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=SMTP
MAIL_HOST=mail.clinicphase.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME="info@clinicphase.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="info@clinicphase.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

and this is my controller,

```
Mail::send('emails.contact_us', [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'subject' => 'Message from website',
            'mobile_number' => $request->mobile_number,
            'visitor_msg' => $request->message
        ], function ($message) use ($data, $site_email) {
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to($site_email);
            $message->subject('Message from website');
        });
```

Comment: how to make your comment is the correct answer?

Comment: I just posted my comment as answer so that you can mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your `config/mail.php` file, you'll see which mailers are setup.

By default in Laravel 7, it has an `smtp` mailer:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7.x/config/mail.php#L37

The mailer names are case-sensitive (just like any other configs). So unless you've changed it, you need to use `smtp` and not `SMTP` in your .env file.